# How to add Category Product Count to JSON-LD?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm an absolute newbie to Opencart, as well as Twig and SQL.
Currently trying to add JSON-LD on categories page:

```
let min_price = $('input#filter_price_min').val();
let max_price = $('input#filter_price_max').val();

data = {
               "@context": "https://schema.org/",
                       "@type": "Product",
                       "name": "{{ heading_title }}",
                       "image": "{{ products[0].thumb }}",
                       "offers": {
                          "@type": "AggregateOffer",
                          "lowPrice": min_price,
                          "highPrice": max_price,
                          "offerCount": "",
                                   "priceCurrency": "RUB"
                                               },
            }
```

I've tried to edit Controller's category.php, but couldn't succeed

The question is - how to get this value: *quantity of products of a certain category*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upd. Solved

Needed to add `$data['product_total'] = $product_total;` right after `$data['results'] = ... / $limit));` in **/catalog/controller/product/category.php** directory

and `{{ product_total }}` to JSON LD

Another main thing to do is to update modificators in opencart admin panel **(admin panel --> modules --> modificators)**